# hashicorp vault - unable to list a secret using the API but can successfully verify using CLI

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I've got a local vault server in development mode so I can learn and understand how to use vault.
In this exercise my goal is to load/put a cert into the secrets engine using the API. I've been able to so with this curl command:

```
curl --header "X-Vault-Token: $VAULT_TOKEN" \
   --request POST \
   --data @payload-cert.json \
   http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/kv-v1/prod/cert1/mysql
```

I can verify this cert exists by running the CLI command:

```
vault kv get kv-v1/prod/cert1/mysql
```

Example output shows its there:

```
==== Data ====
Key     Value
---     -----
cert    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

However, I need to verify this using the API. How do I do that? I'm using this command:

```
curl -s --header "X-Vault-Token:$VAULT_TOKEN" --request LIST http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/kv-v1/prod/cert1/mysql | jq
```

Results show empty:

```
{
  "errors": []
}
```

I just verified it exists using CLI. What am I missing or doing wrong with my curl statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to list a single item, when you need to be trying to list a folder. If you just drop the `mysql` from your URL it should show you the `mysql` item:

```
curl -s --header "X-Vault-Token:$VAULT_TOKEN" --request LIST http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/kv-v1/prod/cert1/ | jq
```

See https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/secret/kv/kv-v1#list-secrets .

If you want to replicate the response you got from the CLI, you want to use a `GET` request:

```
curl -s --header "X-Vault-Token:$VAULT_TOKEN" --request GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/kv-v1/prod/cert1/mysql | jq
```